# Using Django Internationalization with Æ Ø Å characters causing issues

Tags: python, django-templates, special-characters, django-authentication

**EDIT: The solution is, to go to the template causing issues, then pressing "save as" and clicking the arrow next to save. Then pressing the encoding button and choosing utf-8 Unicode. Save the file thereafter**

I am working with the Internationalization feature in Django which lets you translate Django projects.

I've run into a problem where some of my .js files arent translating when using the letters "æ, ø, å".
When attempting i get the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFGoI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, to go to the template causing issues, then pressing "save as" and clicking the arrow next to save. Then pressing the encoding button and choosing utf-8 Unicode. Save the file thereafter